# jquery ajax call returning error when response text is string

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am making an ajax requests with following details:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/cars/70ced046-3061-4d9d-b9ce-7d1291d5b5c0
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Response Headers
Content-Length:36
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:18:45 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

But then the ajax call returns error with the following xhr,status and error objects:

```
function(request, status, error) 

>status
"parsererror"

>error
SyntaxError
arguments: Array[0]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "unexpected_token_number"
__proto__: Error

>request
Object
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
isRejected: function () {
isResolved: function () {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseText: "44550569-871d-49ae-8583-f07ee3a07832"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks, progressCallbacks ) {
__proto__: Object
```

If the response is an integer or any other json, the call works just fine entering the success function. But if the response is string (44550569-871d-49ae-8583-f07ee3a07832) it gives error.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the server side where i was forcing the server to return application/json:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/cars/{id}", produces="application/json")
```

which produces the following response header:

```
Response Headers
Content-Length:36
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:18:45 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Now that i remove the "produces="application/json"" part, it returns following header:

```
Content-Length:36
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Wed, 11 Jul 2012 06:08:00 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: and now everything is fixed. right? But keep in mind, now you expect plain text as response. So if its json, better parse it before using it - jQuery.parseJSON( json )

Answer (score 1):

Because you are expecting the response to be a JSON

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

Paste your ajax calling javascript part, so that I can provide you more information.

Comment: i was not forcing the response to be application/json via the ajax call, but on the server side. Thank you for directing me in the right direction.